# Show that the effective carrier density for electrons is $2\left(\frac{{m_c}^*k_BT}{2\pi\hbar^2}\right)^{3/2}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, density-of-states

> The 3-dimensional free electron density of states (DOS) including spin degeneracy is:
> $$g(E)=\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\left(\frac{2m_e}{\hbar^2}\right)^{3/2}\sqrt{E}$$ where $m_e$ is the electron mass, and $E$ is the energy.
>
> **(a)** Write down the DOS, $g_c(E)$ and $g_v(E)$, for the conduction and valence band edges of a semiconductor using the electron effective masses, ${m_c}^*$ and ${m_v}^*$, and the band edge energies, $E_{c0}$ and $E_{v0}$, respectively.
>
> **(b)** The Fermi-Dirac distribution function is: $f(E)=\left[e^{(E-E_F)/k_BT} + 1\right]^{-1}$, where $E_F$ is the Fermi level energy and $T$ is the temperature. Write down intergrals (with the appropriate limits) governing the total number densities of electrons, $n$, and holes, $p$, in the conduction and valence bands, respectively.
>
> **(c)** In the limit of $(E_{c0}-E_F)\gg k_BT\,$for electrons and $(E_F-E_{v0})\gg k_BT$ for holes, find approximations to the integrands of $n$ and $p$ and solve. Use the standard intergral:
> $$\int_0^{\infty}\sqrt{x}e^{-x}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\tag{1}$$
>
> **(d)** Hence show the the electon, $n$, and hole, $p$, charge carrier densities are:
>
> $$n=N_C\,e^{-\left(E_{c0}-E_F\right)/k_BT}$$
> $$p=N_V\,e^{-\left(E_F-E_{v0}\right)/k_BT}$$
> and derive the functional form of $N_C$ and $N_V$.

---

I can get the right answers for parts $(a)$, $(b)$, and $(c)$. It is part $(d)$ where I cannot get the right answer. I included the answers to the previous parts for completeness:

**(a)**

Density of states for the conduction band is
$$g_c(E)=\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\left(\frac{2{m_c}^*}{\hbar^2}\right)^{3/2}\sqrt{E-E_{c0}}$$
and for the valence band is
$$g_v(E)=\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\left(\frac{2{m_v}^*}{\hbar^2}\right)^{3/2}\sqrt{E_{v0}-E}$$

**(b)**

$$n=\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\left(\frac{2{m_c}^*}{\hbar^2}\right)^{3/2}\int_{E_{c0}}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{E-E_{c0}}}{e^{(E-E_F)/k_BT}+1}dE$$
For the holes $f_h(E)=1-f(E)=\left[e^{-(E-E_F)/k_BT} + 1\right]^{-1}$ so
$$p=\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\left(\frac{2{m_v}^*}{\hbar^2}\right)^{3/2}\int_{-\infty}^{E_{v0}}\frac{\sqrt{E_{v0}-E}}{e^{-(E-E_F)/k_BT}+1}dE$$

**(c)**
Using the approximation that $f(E)=\left[e^{(E-E_F)/k_BT}+1\right]^{-1}\approx e^{(E-E_F)/k_BT}$
$$n\approx\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\left(\frac{2{m_c}^*k_BT}{\hbar^2}\right)^{3/2}e^{-(E_{c0}-E_F)/k_BT}\int_{E=E_{c0}}^{\infty}\sqrt{E-E_{c0}}e^{-(E-E_{c0})/k_BT}dE$$ in the limit of $(E_{c0}-E_F)\gg k_BT\,$for electrons and $(E_F-E_{v0})\gg k_BT$ for holes,
Using $x=({E-E_{c0}})/k_BT$ and noting that $dE=k_BTdx$ and as $E \to \infty, x \to \infty$ and as $E=E_{c0}, x=0$. It follows that:
$$n=\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\left(\frac{2{m_c}^*k_BT}{\hbar^2}\right)^{3/2}e^{-(E_{c0}-E_F)/k_BT}\int_{x=0}^{\infty}\sqrt{x}e^{-x}dx$$
Utilizing $(1)$, I find that:
$$\begin{align}n&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\left(\frac{2{m_c}^*k_BT}{\hbar^2}\right)^{3/2}e^{-(E_{c0}-E_F)/k_BT}\\&=\frac{1}{4\pi^{3/2}}\left(\frac{2{m_c}^*k_BT}{\hbar^2}\right)^{3/2}e^{-(E_{c0}-E_F)/k_BT}\\&\implies n=\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{2{m_c}^*k_BT}{\pi\hbar^2}\right)^{3/2}e^{-(E_{c0}-E_F)/k_BT}\end{align}$$
An analogous expression for the holes, $p$ is
$$p=\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{2{m_v}^*k_BT}{\pi\hbar^2}\right)^{3/2}e^{-(E_F-E_{v0})/k_BT}$$

**(d)**

The last two expressions (for $n$ and $p$) are already in the correct form ($n=N_C\,e^{-(E_{c0}-E_F)/K_BT}$ and $p=N_V\,e^{-(E_F-E_{v0})/K_BT}$). So I identify the *effective carrier densities*, $N_C$ and $N_V$ as

$$N_C=\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{2{m_c}^*k_BT}{\pi\hbar^2}\right)^{3/2}$$
$$N_V=\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{2{m_v}^*k_BT}{\pi\hbar^2}\right)^{3/2}$$

---

*The problem is that the solution states that*:

> We have the expressions as we want them already, we just need to derive the functional forms of the effective carrier densities:
> $$n=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4\pi^2}\left(\frac{2{m_c}^*k_BT}{\hbar^2}\right)^{3/2}e^{-(E_{c0}-E_F)/K_BT}=N_Ce^{-(E_{c0}-E_F)/K_BT}$$
> Where $$N_C=2\frac{\sqrt{4\pi}}{16\pi^2}\left(\frac{2{m_c}^*k_BT}{\hbar^2}\right)^{3/2}=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]{2\left(\frac{{m_c}^*k_BT}{2\pi\hbar^2}\right)^{3/2}}$$

---

I know that the expression in the red box for $N_C$ is correct as I have seen the same expression on p219, (eqn. 42) in "Introduction to Solid State Physics", by Charles Kittel, 7th edition.

But how was the author (of the question in this post) able to reach that result?

Any hints or tips are most appreciated.

---

*Remark: When I started constructing this question I had multiple questions about the previous question parts, now it seems I just cannot get the result at the end. So apologies for such a long post. In fact, if it is just the mathematics I am getting wrong then it may be better placed on Mathematics StackExchange.*

Comment: It seems to me that you are getting the same answer. $2^{3/2}/4=2/2^{3/2}$

Comment: @Urb Thanks for pointing that out, I just couldn't seem to spot this at the time.